# How to concatenate QString and int

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I am trying to set the text that appears on a tab to something like this

```
~Untitled(n)
```

Where "n" is the index of the tab. I am having trouble concatenating the string and integer. This is what I have tried.

```
armaTab->addTab(new QWidget, "~Untitled (" + QString(armaTab->currentIndex() + 1) + ")");
```

With that, i end up getting something that looks like this:

```
~Untitled([])
```

What is the proper way to concatenate the string and integer to produce the desired result?

Comment: The word is [`to concatenate`](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concatenate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `QString::number(n)`. This will convert the integer to a QString which you can concatenate to your original string.

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it.  I didn't realize QString had that option. I'll remember to read the docs thoroughly next time :)

Answer (score 5):

```
"~Untitled (" + QString::number(armaTab->currentIndex() + 1) + ")"
```

= OR =

```
QString("~Untitled(%1)").arg(armaTab->currentIndex() + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`QString` offers the `arg` function:

```
QString("~Untitled %1").arg(armaTab->currentIndex() + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question already have few good answers. I'm adding another alternate way to concatenate string and integer using stringstream

```
stringstream ss(str);
ss<<n;
string temp = ss.str();
```

or we can get the concatenated string by following logic

```
 string temp = str + to_string(n);
```

Now we can get the QString from string:

```
QString str = QString::fromUtf8(temp.c_str());
```